# RocksDB IO Error Lock: No locks available

Tags: ios, react-native, rocksdb, asyncstorage

I'm using RocksDB on iOS and am using an AsyncStorage adapter along with [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). Whenever I launch the app I get the error:

```
Failed to open db at path /Users/chadwilken/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/818C47D2-ECF0-4003-865E-1FCAADCEF624/data/Containers/Data/Application/6C4F8F80-52E3-48B1-8ED5-84FB9F087514/Documents/RKAsyncRocksDBStorage.

RocksDB Status: IO error: lock /Users/chadwilken/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/818C47D2-ECF0-4003-865E-1FCAADCEF624/data/Containers/Data/Application/6C4F8F80-52E3-48B1-8ED5-84FB9F087514/Documents/RKAsyncRocksDBStorage/LOCK: No locks available.
```

The class that works as the adapter is:

```
// Copyright 2004-present Facebook. All Rights Reserved.

#import "AsyncRocksDBStorage.h"
#include <string>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <RCTConvert.h>
#import <RCTLog.h>
#import <RCTUtils.h>

#include <rocksdb/db.h>
#include <rocksdb/merge_operator.h>
#include <rocksdb/options.h>
#include <rocksdb/slice.h>
#include <rocksdb/status.h>

static NSString *const RKAsyncRocksDBStorageDirectory = @"RKAsyncRocksDBStorage";

namespace {
    rocksdb::Slice SliceFromString(NSString *string)
    {
        return rocksdb::Slice((const char *)[string UTF8String], [string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }

    void deepMergeInto(NSMutableDictionary *output, NSDictionary *input) {
        for (NSString *key in input) {
            id inputValue = input[key];
            if ([inputValue isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                NSMutableDictionary *nestedOutput;
                id outputValue = output[key];
                if ([outputValue isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
                    nestedOutput = outputValue;
                } else {
                    if ([outputValue isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                        nestedOutput = [outputValue mutableCopy];
                    } else {
                        output[key] = [inputValue copy];
                    }
                }
                if (nestedOutput) {
                    deepMergeInto(nestedOutput, inputValue);
                    output[key] = nestedOutput;
                }
            } else {
                output[key] = inputValue;
            }
        }
    }

    class JSONMergeOperator : public rocksdb::AssociativeMergeOperator {
    public:
        virtual bool Merge(const rocksdb::Slice &key,
                           const rocksdb::Slice *existingValue,
                           const rocksdb::Slice &newValue,
                           std::string *mergedValue,
                           rocksdb::Logger *logger) const override {

            NSError *error;
            NSMutableDictionary *existingDict;
            if (existingValue) {
                NSString *existingString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:existingValue->data()];
                existingDict = RCTJSONParseMutable(existingString, &error);
                if (error) {
                    RCTLogError(@"Parse error in RKAsyncRocksDBStorage merge operation.  Error:\n%@\nString:\n%@", error, existingString);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Nothing to merge, just assign the string without even parsing.
                mergedValue->assign(newValue.data(), newValue.size());
                return true;
            }

            NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:newValue.data()];
            NSMutableDictionary *newDict = RCTJSONParse(newString, &error);
            deepMergeInto(existingDict, newDict);
            NSString *mergedNSString = RCTJSONStringify(existingDict, &error);
            mergedValue->assign([mergedNSString UTF8String], [mergedNSString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            return true;
        }

        virtual const char *Name() const override {
            return "JSONMergeOperator";
        }
    };
}  // namespace

@implementation AsyncRocksDBStorage
{
    rocksdb::DB *_db;
}

@synthesize methodQueue = _methodQueue;

static NSString *RCTGetStorageDirectory()
{
    static NSString *storageDirectory = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        storageDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject;
        storageDirectory = [storageDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:RKAsyncRocksDBStorageDirectory];
    });
    return storageDirectory;
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (BOOL)ensureDirectorySetup:(NSError **)error
{
    if (_db) {
        return YES;
    }
    rocksdb::Options options;
    options.create_if_missing = true;
    RCTAssert(error != nil, @"Must provide error pointer.");
    rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options, [RCTGetStorageDirectory() UTF8String], &_db);
    if (!status.ok() || !_db) {
        RCTLogError(@"Failed to open db at path %@.\n\nRocksDB Status: %s.\n\nNSError: %@", RCTGetStorageDirectory(), status.ToString().c_str(), *error);
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"rocksdb" code:100 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Failed to open db"}];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(multiGet:(NSStringArray *)keys
                  callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    NSDictionary *errorOut;
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:keys.count];
    BOOL success = [self ensureDirectorySetup:&error];
    if (!success || error) {
        errorOut = RCTMakeError(@"Failed to setup directory", nil, nil);
    } else {
        std::vector<rocksdb::Slice> sliceKeys;
        sliceKeys.reserve(keys.count);
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            sliceKeys.push_back(SliceFromString(key));
        }
        std::vector<std::string> values;
        std::vector<rocksdb::Status> statuses = _db->MultiGet(rocksdb::ReadOptions(), sliceKeys, &values);
        RCTAssert(values.size() == keys.count, @"Key and value arrays should be equal size");
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < values.size(); ii++) {
            id value = [NSNull null];
            auto status = statuses[ii];
            if (!status.IsNotFound()) {
                if (!status.ok()) {
                    errorOut = RCTMakeError(@"RKAsyncRocksDB failed getting key: ", keys[ii], keys[ii]);
                } else {
                    value = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:values[ii].c_str()];
                }
            }
            [result addObject:@[keys[ii], value]];
        }
    }
    if (callback) {
        callback(@[errorOut ? @[errorOut] : [NSNull null], result]);
    }
}

// kvPairs is a list of key-value pairs, e.g. @[@[key1, val1], @[key2, val2], ...]
// TODO: write custom RCTConvert category method for kvPairs
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(multiSet:(NSArray *)kvPairs
                  callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    auto updates = rocksdb::WriteBatch();
    for (NSArray *kvPair in kvPairs) {
        NSStringArray *pair = [RCTConvert NSStringArray:kvPair];
        if (pair.count == 2) {
            updates.Put(SliceFromString(kvPair[0]), SliceFromString(kvPair[1]));
        } else {
            if (callback) {
                callback(@[@[RCTMakeAndLogError(@"Input must be an array of [key, value] arrays, got: ", kvPair, nil)]]);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    [self _performWriteBatch:&updates callback:callback];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(multiMerge:(NSArray *)kvPairs
                  callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    auto updates = rocksdb::WriteBatch();
    for (NSArray *kvPair in kvPairs) {
        NSStringArray *pair = [RCTConvert NSStringArray:kvPair];
        if (pair.count == 2) {
            updates.Merge(SliceFromString(pair[0]), SliceFromString(pair[1]));
        } else {
            if (callback) {
                callback(@[@[RCTMakeAndLogError(@"Input must be an array of [key, value] arrays, got: ", kvPair, nil)]]);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    [self _performWriteBatch:&updates callback:callback];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(multiRemove:(NSArray *)keys
                  callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    auto updates = rocksdb::WriteBatch();
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        updates.Delete(SliceFromString(key));
    }
    [self _performWriteBatch:&updates callback:callback];
}

// TODO (#5906496): There's a lot of duplication in the error handling code here - can we refactor this?

- (void)_performWriteBatch:(rocksdb::WriteBatch *)updates callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback
{
    NSDictionary *errorOut;
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [self ensureDirectorySetup:&error];
    if (!success || error) {
        errorOut = RCTMakeError(@"Failed to setup storage", nil, nil);
    } else {
        rocksdb::Status status = _db->Write(rocksdb::WriteOptions(), updates);
        if (!status.ok()) {
            errorOut = RCTMakeError(@"Failed to write to RocksDB database.", nil, nil);
        }
    }
    if (callback) {
        callback(@[errorOut ? @[errorOut] : [NSNull null]]);
    }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(clear:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    //  [self _nullOutDB];
    //  NSDictionary *errorOut;
    //  NSError *error;
    //  NSURL *userDirectory = getOrCreateRocksDBPath(&error);
    //  if (!userDirectory) {
    //    errorOut = RCTMakeError(@"Failed to setup storage", nil, nil);
    //  } else {
    //    rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DestroyDB([[userDirectory path] UTF8String], rocksdb::Options());
    //    if (!status.ok()) {
    //      errorOut = RCTMakeError(@"RocksDB:clear failed to destroy db at path ", [userDirectory path], nil);
    //    }
    //  }
    //  if (callback) {
    //    callback(@[errorOut ?: [NSNull null]]);
    //  }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getAllKeys:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *allKeys = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSDictionary *errorOut;
    BOOL success = [self ensureDirectorySetup:&error];
    if (!success || error) {
        errorOut = RCTMakeError(@"Failed to setup storage", nil, nil);
    } else {
        rocksdb::Iterator *it = _db->NewIterator(rocksdb::ReadOptions());
        for (it->SeekToFirst(); it->Valid(); it->Next()) {
            [allKeys addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:it->key().data()]];
        }
    }
    if (callback) {
        callback(@[errorOut ?: [NSNull null], allKeys]);
    }
}

@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

"No locks available" RocksDB error means that you're trying to open RocksDB twice on the same directory. The second RocksDB open will fail with this error. Hope this helps.

Comment: I found a similar answer pertaining to this on Android, the problem is that I can't find in source code where this would be happening

Comment: I encountered this issue too today with `librocksdb4.1` on Ubuntu 16.04. Interestingly, this error persists even when you _delete the directory_. Usually, database applications do locking based on files in the file system; if you delete them, the lock is essentially gone (and the thing it is protecting is also gone). But rocksdb seems to have some form of global singleton in-memory file path lookup table, that doesn't care about what's actually on the file system. Thus it claims "no locks available" even if you mount another FS over the dir ... (continuing in next comment)

Comment: ... (continuing previous comment) This looks like hacky engineering shortcuts in rocksdb to me instead of implementing proper file based locking (IIRC sqlite doesn't have that type of a problem), but I have not investigated the issue thorougly yet so maybe there is a legitimate reason to do so.

Comment: This is actually the cause of the error. Somehow I called a function which had open, inside of it, and on second call to that function I got this error.

Comment: I think RocksDB's file locking mechanism is taken from LevelDB, which explains its reasoning here: https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/53e280b56866ac4c90a9f5fcfe02ebdfd4a19832/util/env_posix.cc#L466-L468

Comment: What happens if you open RocksDB twice onto the same directory via two separate threads? So far my test shows no exception, but will the database be corrupted when each thread writes and reads from the database?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs even if you delete the rocksdb files. 
db.close() works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone gets here while working with Kafka Streams on an M1 Mac:

I just got a `RocksDBException ... No locks found` in a Spring Kafka Streams app on my M1 Mac, and resolved it by swapping to an x86 based JDK form the ARM/AArch64 JDK I had been using...